# how can I know if backspace or delete was pressed in TextChanged event of textbox

Tags: silverlight, textbox

I use the TextChanged event of a textbox.

for instance I have the text in the textbox:
"a  b"- 2 spaces between a,b
I go in the middle of the 2 spaces, and hit backspace. I can not check by comparing the new text with the old which key was pressed (if backspace or delete was pressed, the newtext is the 
same "a b"-1 space between letters.

How can I check which key was pressed?

Comment: Why don't you use the KeyPress event then?

Comment: @Alireza: Because you can't determine if Delete or Backspace was pressed from the `KeyPress` event. You need to use `KeyDown`. `KeyPress` is only raised by *character* keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you care? If you're handling the `TextChanged` event, you're not supposed to care *what* about the text was changed, just the fact that it *was*.

If you need to care about *what* specifically was changed, you need to handle a lower-level event, like [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown.aspx):

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        // The user deleted a character
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed statement:     if (e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Delete)

Comment: Hi, @Jeff! Thanks for the comment. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone will find this helpful.

I used an integer, that counts length of current characters. It updates with the event.
Every time, the event is triggered, I check, if the length of the counter is longer than the current length of the text. If it is, we know, there was something deleted.

```
    private int counter = 0;

private void TextChangedEvent(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e){

if(counter > textbox.text){
counter = text.Length;
//deleted
}

else{
counter = text.Length;
//added}
```